# WebView reload after connection recovered?

Tags: java, android, webview, broadcastreceiver

[SOLVED] [FIXED CODE BELOW]

It is a small app with a webview, i want to reload this when connection to internet is back. I open the app (with internet connected) and it shows the web (google.com.ar), when I disconnect WiFi and 3G if I navigate on the web it show error message, it is ok, but if I reconnect WiFi the app crashes. What is the problem? I think is in the BroadReceiver, in the manifest i have android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE and android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE.

Thanks.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.app;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    static WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        StrictMode.enableDefaults();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com.ar");

        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() );

    }

}
```

ConnectionBroadReceiver.java

```
package com.example.app;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class ConnectionBroadReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)    
        context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            MainActivity.myWebView.reload();
        } else {
        }

    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.example.app.ConnectionBroadReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please provide the exception that caused your application to crash. You can get it from LogCat.

Comment: Can you provide code of your Manifest?

Comment: 05-08 11:25:46.053: W/System.err(23238): at 
com.example.fourbyte.ConnectionBroadReceiver.onReceive (ConnectionBroadReceiver.java:20)

05-08 11:25:46.053: W/System.err(23238): at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:2426)